# Using HtmlAgility to get the OID from this webpage

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Hello I am having an Issue and some OuterHTML Text from this webpage using the HtmlAgility library for C#

How would I iterate through the table rows to get the OID number. Here is the HTML structure of the webpage.

```html
<div class="box-header with-border">
<h3 class="box-title">Imported Objects</h3>
  </div><table class="table table-condensed table-striped"><tr><td><i><small>pduAgent</small></i></td><td style="white-space: nowrap;"> <a href="#notifyInternalStatus" id="notifyInternalStatus" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Sent whenever the PDU internal status changes.</pre>">notifyInternalStatus <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.0.52</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 80px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/weather-severe-alert.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#notifyTest" id="notifyTest" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Sent whenever the trap test feature is used by the communication card.</pre>">notifyTest <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.0.53</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 80px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/weather-severe-alert.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#notifyStrappingStatus" id="notifyStrappingStatus" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Sent whenever the strapping communication status changes.</pre>">notifyStrappingStatus <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.0.54</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 64px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/draw-line.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#units" id="units">units</a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label> <span class="label label-warn"></span></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 80px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/code-variable.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#unitsPresent" id="unitsPresent" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Each unit is identified by a Strapping Index.  This object returns a comma-delimited list of the
Strapping Indexes of all units present in the strapping group.  For example, if units 0, 1, 5,
and 7 are present, this value will be '0,1,5,7'.  For units that do not support strapping,
a Strapping Index of '0' is assumed.</pre>">unitsPresent <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.1</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 80px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/games-config-board.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#unitTable" id="unitTable" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>A list of units.  In most cases this list will only contain one entry.
However, some units have a 'strapping' feature which allow units to be
daisy-chained together such that all of them can be accessed through
the SNMP interface of the master.  If strapping is enabled, the 
strapping indexes of the units that can be accessed will be listed in the
unitsPresent object.</pre>">unitTable <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 96px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-row.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#unitEntry" id="unitEntry" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>An entry for a PDU.</pre>">unitEntry <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" />  <a href="#inputCount" id="inputCount" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Number of inputs on this ePDU.</pre>">inputCount <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.20</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#groupCount" id="groupCount" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Number of groups on this ePDU.  Groups include breakers, outlet sections,
and user-defined groups.</pre>">groupCount <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.21</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#outletCount" id="outletCount" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Number of outlets on this ePDU.</pre>">outletCount <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.22</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#temperatureCount" id="temperatureCount" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Max number of temperature measurements on this ePDU.</pre>">temperatureCount <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.23</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#humidityCount" id="humidityCount" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Max number of humidity measurements on this ePDU.</pre>">humidityCount <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.24</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#contactCount" id="contactCount" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Max number of contact sensors on this ePDU.</pre>">contactCount <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.25</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#partNumber" id="partNumber" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Part number of the unit.</pre>">partNumber <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.3</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#communicationStatus" id="communicationStatus" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Status of the internal communication with the PDU.</pre>">communicationStatus <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.30</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#internalStatus" id="internalStatus" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Status of the internal failure inside the PDU.</pre>">internalStatus <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.31</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#strappingStatus" id="strappingStatus" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Status of the external communication with a strapping unit.</pre>">strappingStatus <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.32</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#serialNumber" id="serialNumber" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Serial number of the unit.</pre>">serialNumber <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.4</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#userName" id="userName" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Username used to log into the PDU.</pre>">userName <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.40</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#commInterface" id="commInterface" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Communications interface used to log into the PDU.</pre>">commInterface <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.41</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#firmwareVersion" id="firmwareVersion" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Firmware version.</pre>">firmwareVersion <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.5</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#unitName" id="unitName" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Descriptive name for the unit.</pre>">unitName <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.6</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#lcdControl" id="lcdControl" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Control the local LCD.</pre>">lcdControl <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.7</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#clockValue" id="clockValue" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Clock value.  This could be from either a real-time clock (in which case
it is likely writeable) or from a time server via NTP (probably read-only).</pre>">clockValue <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.8</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#temperatureScale" id="temperatureScale" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Scale used to return temperature objects.</pre>">temperatureScale <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.2.1.9</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 80px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/games-config-board.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#unitControlTable" id="unitControlTable" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>A list of units that have controllable outlets.</pre>">unitControlTable <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.3</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 96px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-row.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#unitControlEntry" id="unitControlEntry" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>An entry for a PDU which has controllable outlets.</pre>">unitControlEntry <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.3.1</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#unitControlOffCmd" id="unitControlOffCmd" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Unit-level outlet control command.

Once the command is issued, outlets will turn Off.
0-n : Time in seconds until the outlet Sequence Off command is issued
-1 : Cancel a pending unit-level Off command 

When read, returns -1 if no command is pending, or the current downcount in seconds of a pending command.
          
          Certain ePDUs (mainly those with part numbers beginning with IPV or IPC) do not support delayed control
          commands.  These will respond with an error if a command value of &gt; 0 is written to this object.</pre>">unitControlOffCmd <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.3.1.2</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#unitControlOnCmd" id="unitControlOnCmd" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Unit-level outlet control command.

Once the command is issued, outlets will turn On according to their outletControlSequenceDelay value.
0-n : Time in seconds until the outlet Sequence On command is issued
-1 : Cancel a pending unit-level On command 

When read, returns -1 if no command is pending, or the current downcount in seconds of a pending command.
          
          Certain ePDUs (mainly those with part numbers beginning with IPV or IPC) do not support delayed control
          commands.  These will respond with an error if a command value of &gt; 0 is written to this object.</pre>">unitControlOnCmd <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.1.3.1.3</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 64px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/draw-line.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#conformance" id="conformance">conformance</a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label> <span class="label label-warn"></span></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.25</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 80px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/draw-line.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#objectGroups" id="objectGroups">objectGroups</a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label> <span class="label label-warn"></span></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.25.5</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 64px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/draw-line.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#inputs" id="inputs">inputs</a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label> <span class="label label-warn"></span></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.3</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 80px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/games-config-board.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#inputTable" id="inputTable" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>List of inputs to the PDU.</pre>">inputTable <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.3.1</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 96px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-row.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#inputEntry" id="inputEntry" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>An entry for a particular input.</pre>">inputEntry <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.3.1.1</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#inputIndex" id="inputIndex" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>A unique value for each input.  Its value ranges from 1 to inputCount.</pre>">inputIndex <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.3.1.1.1</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#inputFeedName" id="inputFeedName" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>A descriptive name for the input.</pre>">inputFeedName <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.3.1.1.10</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#inputType" id="inputType" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Type of input - single phase, split phase, three phase delta, or three
phase wye.</pre>">inputType <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.3.1.1.2</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#inputFrequency" id="inputFrequency" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Units are 0.1 Hz; divide by ten to get Hz.</pre>">inputFrequency <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.3.1.1.3</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#inputFrequencyStatus" id="inputFrequencyStatus" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Status of the measured input frequency relative to the nominal frequency and the admitted tolerance.</pre>">inputFrequencyStatus <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.3.1.1.4</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#inputVoltageCount" id="inputVoltageCount" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Number of input voltage measurements on this ePDU.</pre>">inputVoltageCount <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.3.1.1.5</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#contactProbeStatus" id="contactProbeStatus" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>Indicates whether a probe is connected or not.
Will not be returned  if the contact sensor is internal to the ePDU,
in that case only contactState should be read.</pre>">contactProbeStatus <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.7.3.1.3</td></tr><tr><td><img style="width: 112px; height:1px;" src="/images/1x1.png" /><img height="18" width="18" src="/images/edit-table-delete-column.svg" style="margin-top: -2px" /> <a href="#contactState" id="contactState" class="tooltip-from-data" style="cursor: pointer;" data-rel="tooltip" data-tooltip="<pre>The state of the contact sensor.</pre>">contactState <img style="width: 12px; height:12px; top:-5; position: relative;" src="/images/help-about.svg" /></a></td><td><label class="label label-small label-info"></label></td><td>.1.3.6.1.4.1.534.6.6.7.7.3.1.4</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

I have tried multiple ways but Ive only been able to get the Last OID not all of the OIDs in the document. for refernce the text I want to get are the numbers like .1.3.6.1.4.1.534 etc
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select all nodes that `td` starts with `.` . Maybe you can use better locator but for this particular html code this "strategy" works just fine.

```
var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//td[starts-with(text(), '.')]");
foreach (var item in table)
{
    var oid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.InnerText) ? item.InnerText : "";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oid))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(oid); 
    }
    
}
```

The above code produces this result

[image]